# don't understand accepting prefix as an argument

Tags: javascript, function

So I was to create a triangle of asterisks based on the user's input:

http://jsfiddle.net/u6mjm/

and I don't understand what does it mean to modify the `makeTriangle` function to accepts a prefix as an argument and also each line of output should incorporate this prefix. What does it mean by prefix as an argument? I'm confused

Comment: Unless you provide the full problem statement, our guess is just as good as yours with respect to what "prefix" means in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that your question has to do with the meaning of the words "prefix as an argument." The plain sense of the words is that you should modify `makeTriangle` to take an additional argument that should be printed as a prefix to each line of output. A *prefix* in this context simply means a string that appears at the start of each line.